# What do "tapped" and "checkered" mean in "...Brown was tapped to operate shelters in New York despite a checkered past..."?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

The Headline is:

> Jack Brown was **tapped** to operate shelters in New York despite a **checkered** past, The New York Times found in a recent investigation.

I can't figure out: "tapped" (although I can have a clue about that) and "checkered" what is the meaning of tenses words give that context??

Comment: It's [definition #5 in Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/tap_1): ***choose for task*** (​AMERICAN ​INFORMAL) - one of their example usages being *The President has tapped a former Justice Department official to lead the FBI*. But as a Brit I rarely encounter this usage, and my *first* assumption on reading the example here was that ***tapped*** was a typo for ***tipped*** (suggested as a likely candidate, the way racing tipsters "tip" the horse they *think* will win). So don't use this if your audience / readers are Brits!

Comment: Also [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/chequered) - *if someone has had **a chequered past** or a chequered career, they have experienced both successes and failures*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - also a number of disreputable incidents, maybe? Trouble with the police?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Yes, in principle. But I suspect in the *exact* cited context, the NYT are more likely to be wanting to question Brown's *competence* (because he's been responsible for at least *some* failures), rather than questioning his *integrity* (because he's a known sleazeball). Maybe it just depends on how much they care what Brown thinks of NYT, and/or whether they risk being sued for slander. Someone who reads NYT regularly might know more about their likely intention there.

Comment: @FumbleFungers - you've contributed a lot with your answers . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"Tap someone to do something" means to select them to do some specific action